# Cake PHP 2.x Auth data is only available in one controller and null in the rest. Any idea why?

Tags: session, cakephp, authentication, controller, authorization

I am new to CakePHP, and despite searching high and low I can't find an answer to what seems like a trivial problem. The issue is that after logging in through my UserController I am losing the data found in `$this->Auth->user()` on all other Controllers. Any views not associated with UserController will always have null data and `$this->Auth->loggedIn()` will return false.

In my AppController class, I have attempted to save the data into a variable inside `beforeFilter()` so that I may check the variable in my views, but it doesn't make a difference. Here is the relavent code for my UserController and AppController classes:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

// Pass settings in $components array
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index')
    )
);

public function beforeFilter() {
    //debug($this->Auth->user());
    $this->set('loggedIn', $this->Auth->user());    

    }

}
```

Users class:

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class UsersController extends AppController {

public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
public $name = 'Users';

public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
}

public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
        }
    }
}

public function logout() {
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}

}
```

I have also made sure to use `parent::beforeFilter()` in my other controllers.

Comment: Make sure PHP can write sessions (you can use DebugKit to inspect the Cake session). Then add `$this->Session->flash('auth');` to your layout to output auth-related messages.

Comment: remvoe App::uses('AppController', 'Controller'); from user controller.

Comment: I've been using `if ($this->Session->check('Auth.User.id')) { ... }` to check if the user is logged in. It works from any controller, view or layout. Not sure if it's the right way of doing things, but it definitely works. I can also access any of the other information in the User's record with things like `$this->Session->read('Auth.User.email')` -- is that what you meant?

Comment: `$this->Session` gives me the same troubles, I suppose I should've mentioned that in the original post. It seems as if there are two different sessions being created, with the second one being empty..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I found the solution. In my HomeController, which was the page I was always viewing after I logged in, it seems as though there was some invisible character following the closing php declaration `?>` (which was not needed either) so I deleted it and the `?>` and voila, everything is working as expected.

I was tipped off that something was amiss after I tried manually using `session_start()` in my layout and I was given an error about the line after `?>` in the HomeController class.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should set `loggedIn` in the `beforeRender()` function in your `AppController` class instead of `beforeFilter()`.

```
public function beforeRender() {
    $this->set('loggedIn', $this->Auth->user());   
}
```

Comment: I had previously tried this as well. I have think I have found a solution though, thanks.